# "like to be..." vs. "like being..." (and why?)

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following?

> A) *She likes to be looked at.*
>
> B) *She likes being looked at.*

Could you please elaborate your explanations? The more detail, the better.

Comment: Those two sentences would have the same meaning to me.

Comment: Both are correct, and there's some elaboration in [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96744/15299), and [possibly this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96744/15299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joe says, in most such contexts there's no discernible difference in meaning. But in some contexts there *is* a possible distinction between infinitive/gerund (or simple/continuous tense). For example,...

> *Always **tell** the truth, but don't always **be telling** the truth.*

...which could be mirrored by something closer to OP's example, such as...

> *I want you always **to tell** the truth, but not always **to be telling** the truth.*

In such constructions we're forced to acknowledge that the ***-ing*** versions emphasise *continuously* doing something (in this case, the intended sense is that whenever you *do* say something it should be true, but sometimes it would be better not to say anything at all).

---

But in OP's example it would be stretching a point to suggest that the first version means *if she **happens** to be aware that people are looking at her, she likes it*, and that the second version carries more the implication that she's *only really content **when** people are looking at her*.

---

It's also worth noting what happens if we substitute a different verb...

> 1: *She wants to be looked at.*
>    2: ?? *She wants being looked at.*
>    3: *She wants looking at.*

...where #2 wouldn't normally be considered grammatically acceptable, and #3 would almost always be interpreted as an idiomatic format meaning *[objectively speaking] it would be better if she were looked at*. Some people would allow that interpretation for #1, but it would more naturally be seen as equivalent (or at least, extremely similar) to both OP's examples.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are the same. In English, both the infinitive (to _____) and the gerund (*_*__ing) are used as nouns. This makes both of them the same.

Comment: hank you  so much, but which one and when would you rather apply them in writing/speech?

Comment: @nima_persian I would use them interchangeably. When I read the two sentences, I don't perceive even a subtle difference, though others are free to weigh in, and I can see myself using either one without even a preference for one form over the other.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to use the infinitive (to be) because it fits more with how other languages would do it (i think)